# why am I getting 0 in TN and FN in confusion matrix using keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sklearn-pandas, confusion-matrix

I try to do NN text classification using keras. But when I do confusion matrix it get 0 in TN and FN. It strange cause when I make model using sklearn MLPClassifier with same data and hyperparameter I don't get 0 in TN and FN.
This is the model I built in keras:

```
model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Dense(300, input_dim= Train_X2_Tfidf.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model3.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.01)
model3.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model3.summary()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",mode='min',patience=10)
history3 = model3.fit(Train_X2_Tfidf, Train_Y2, epochs=400, verbose=1, 
                      validation_split=0.2, batch_size=32,  callbacks =[es])
```

Keras model get confusion matrix like this:

```
y_pred = np.argmax(model3.predict(Test_X2_Tfidf), axis=-1)

print(confusion_matrix(Test_Y2, y_pred))
print(classification_report(Test_Y2, y_pred))
print('Confusion matrix:')
confusion_matrix(Test_Y2, y_pred)
from nltk.metrics.scores import precision
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(Test_Y2, y_pred), annot=True, fmt=".0f", ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("y_head")
plt.ylabel("y_true")
plt.show()

cm = confusion_matrix(Test_Y2, y_pred)

[[186   0]
 [557   0]]
```

With same data and hyperparameter, confusion matrix that I get using sklearn MLPClassifier model is like this:

```
[[146  40]
 [ 35 522]]
```

What's wrong with my keras model?

Comment: argmax is not used in binary classification, so all your predictions are incorrect.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  can i know how to predict the correct y_pred?

Comment: y_pred = model.predict(blabla) > 0.5